# python dictionary with function and arguments

Tags: python, function, dictionary, arguments

I want to use a dictionary to call functions with arguments, ie this simple program. I'm a very novice coder in python. what am I doing wrong?
output:

```
what name? : s
what name? : f


f



s

want to write or read? w/r: 
w
want singers or band members? s/b: 
s
1

```

code:

```
def addToFile(filename, lineString):
  file = open(filename,"a")
  file.write(lineString + "\n")
  file.close()
  return 1
    
def readFile(filename):
  file = open(filename)
  for line in file:
    print(line)
  file.close()
  return 2

whatToDo = {
  "ws": addToFile("band.txt",input("what name? : ")),
  "wb": addToFile("singers.txt",input("what name? : ")),
  "rs": readFile("singers.txt"),
  "rb": readFile("band.txt")
}
def promptWrite():
  print("want to write or read? w/r: ")
  choice = str(input())
  print("want singers or band members? s/b: ")
  choice += str(input())
  val = whatToDo[choice]
  print(val)

promptWrite()
```

I didn't know If I needed to have a value or something, so I put the returns in the functions and had val. That isn't nessisary, I just drafted this up as an example program.
I know that you can have a dictionary with the names of the functions and call
`dictionaryName[whateverthing]()` to run the function, but I don't know how to have the arguments vary in that

Comment: Please check the indentation of your code. It currently looks like the functions are defined inside `addToFile()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the functions when you create the dictionary, not when you access the dictionary. Use `lambda` to create anonymous functions, then add `()` when you fetch from the dictionary to call it.

```
def addToFile(filename, lineString):
  file = open(filename,"a")
  file.write(lineString + "\n")
  file.close()
  return 1
    
def readFile(filename):
  file = open(filename)
  for line in file:
    print(line)
  file.close()
  return 2

whatToDo = {
  "ws": lambda: addToFile("band.txt",input("what name? : ")),
  "wb": lambda: addToFile("singers.txt",input("what name? : ")),
  "rs": lambda: readFile("singers.txt"),
  "rb": lambda: readFile("band.txt")
}
def promptWrite():
  print("want to write or read? w/r: ")
  choice = input()
  print("want singers or band members? s/b: ")
  choice += input()
  val = whatToDo[choice]()
  print(val)

promptWrite()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set functions with parameters to be executed in a dictionary, but you can store functions to call them after, with the corresponding dict key and parenthesis. Example:

```
my_dict['write_output'] = print
my_dict['write_output']('hello from my key')
```

IMHO, storing your functions in dict keys is a design incosistency. Dicts are mutable objects, then someone could overwrite your keys without any restriction and mess up your code everywhere. Not a good idea at all.